# How to use SessionAwareCoreService with LDAP?

Tags: core-service, ldap

I have created the .NET application by using Core Service, specifically ISessionAwareCoreService.
Tridion used Windows authentication, but it is modified to LDAP authentication.

So I have to modify the Core Service application to use LDAP authentication, but it doesn't work so far.

Any idea to modify following source code to use LDAP authentication?

```
public static ISessionAwareCoreService GetCoreSeriviceClient()
{
    ISessionAwareCoreService client;
    ConfigFile.ConfigIni configFile = new ConfigFile.ConfigIni();
    ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService>("netTcp_201603");
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password");
    factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = networkCredential;

    client = factory.CreateChannel();
    return client;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I modified my program following answers and did some trials, but I couldn't make `ISessionAwareCoreService` work with LDAP authentication. So I replaced `ISessionAwareCoreService` to `ICoreService` , and replaced `netTcp` binding to `basicHttp` binding.

```
public static ICoreService GetCoreSeriviceClient()
{
    ICoreService client;
    ConfigFile.ConfigIni configFile = new ConfigFile.ConfigIni();
    ChannelFactory<ICoreService> factory = new ChannelFactory<ICoreService>("basicHttp_201603");

    factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = configFile.GetValue("user", "name");
    factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = configFile.GetValue("user", "password");

    client = factory.CreateChannel();
    return client;
}
```

And binding configuration is followning, set Basic to clientCredentialType

```
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  sendTimeout="00:20:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <!-- For LDAP or SSO authentication of transport credentials, use clientCredentialType="**Basic**" -->
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Did you configure your [Tridion-Home]\webservices\Web.config to LDAP authentication? I can see you are using the NetTcpEndpoint, Is that core service you are running inside the cms server?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you will have to change both server-side and client-side WCF configuration, so Message based security based on username/password is used instead of Windows authentication.

Secondly, you will have to provide the username/password in code in a different way than you have in your example:

```
factory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = networkCredential;
```

Is specific for Windows authentication.

For a general username/password token, you use something like:

```
factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for without config to call coreservice:

```
static ISessionAwareCoreService GetCoreSeriviceClient(string hostname, string username, string password)
        {
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding
            {
                MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                Name = "netTcp_201603",
                TransactionFlow = true,
                TransactionProtocol = TransactionProtocol.OleTransactions,
                ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue
                }
            };

            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(String.Format("net.tcp://{0}:2660/CoreService/201603/netTcp",hostname));
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService>(binding, endpoint);

            var credentialBehaviour = factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials>();
            credentialBehaviour.UserName.UserName = username;
            credentialBehaviour.UserName.Password = password;
            return factory.CreateChannel();
        }
```